# How to correctly use an unordered_map C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, hashmap

I wanted to create a `std::unordered_map` with a custom hash function. I am having trouble figuring out where to declare/how to use my `unordered_map` though.

Here is the situation. I have a class called `Object`. It's super simple and merely contains an integer `id`. Here is the header file:

```
// Object.hpp
class Object {
    public:
        Object();
        ~Object(){};
        int   Id();
        void setId(int i);
    private:
        int id;
};
```

I have a class called `DataSet` that acts as a container which will hold millions of these `Object`s. For simplicities sake, I only want to be able to construct a `DataSet`, add an `Object` to the `DataSet`, delete an `Object` by ID from the `DataSet`, clear the `DataSet`, and get the size of the `DataSet`.

The structure I want to (and am required to) use in my `DataSet` class is a an `std::unordered_map`. For this map, I want the key to be the integer id associated with an `Object`, and the actual `Object*` itself as the value. Finally I have this hash function that I want to use for the `unordered_map`. Here is what I currently have in my `DataSet` header file:

```
// DataSet.hpp
struct HashKey {
    unsigned int hash(unsigned int x) {
        x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
        x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
        x = ((x >> 16) ^ x);
        return x;
    }
};

class DataSet{

public:
    std::unordered_map<int,Object*,HashKey> objects;

    DataSet();
    ~DataSet();

    int addObject(Object *object);
    void clear();
    int deleteObject(int id);
    int getSize();
};
```

As of right now I'm just trying to figure out how to create `addObject` in `DataSet.cpp`. Here is my (broken) try:

```
int DataSet::addObject(Object *object)
{
    objects.emplace(object->Id(),object);
    return 1;
}
```

When compiled, I end up with this error:

```
type 'const HashKey' does not provide a call operator
        {return static_cast<const _Hash&>(*this)(__x.__cc.first);}
```

What I eventually want to be able to do is in another file called `driver.cpp`, have a for loop that will add millions of `Object`s. It would look like this:

```
DataSet container;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    Object *object = new Object();
    object->setId(i);
    container.addObject(object);
}
```

Is there some way to make the `unordered_map` so that I can accomplish this? As a side note, I am required to use the current `DataSet` class and the current `Object` class as is. I just need to make a `std::unordered_map` for it.

Comment: Hash must have `op()` defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the hash function as a `const` *call operator* (i.e. `operator()`) that takes an object of the *key type* and returns `size_t`:

```
size_t operator()(int x) const { ... }
```